# Trying to get the HTML source code of my app page on the App Store

Tags: html, ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to parse the page of my own app at the app store using this code

```
  NSError *error = nil;

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id892887222?ls=1&mt=8"];

  NSStringEncoding encoding;
  NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                              encoding:encoding
                                                 error:&error];
```

webData is nil and `[error localizedDescription]` shows **The file “id892887222” couldn’t be opened.**

I suppose this happens because this page is dynamic, created on-the-fly by pulling a database, but how do I get the source code of this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gives me the HTML of the page as a NSString object:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError *error;
NSString *contentsOfAppleComAsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id892887222?ls=1&mt=8"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
if(contentsOfAppleComAsString)
{
    NSLog(@"contents of Apple.com is %@", contentsOfAppleComAsString);
} else {
    NSLog(@"error from trying to get contents of Apple.com is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: sorry but your answer is exactly the one I have posted that does not work. Try yourself for that url.

Comment: No, there's a subtle difference in my code.  I'm using "[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: **usedEncoding:** error:]" API.  Try that.

Comment: tried your version. contentsOfAppleComAsString is nil. Have you by any chance run this code? Are you getting the source code?  (error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted)

Comment: When I run it as a MacOS Cocoa application, I get the contents of that web page.

Comment: can you please send me a link to download the project you have tried that? I need to compare yours to mine to see where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: found the problem. It was a limitation on the sandbox entitlements! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

1. use NSASCIIStringEncoding instead of  NSStringEncoding in your current code and try. Otherwise,

load your app page in a webview (make it hidden if you dont want others to see it) and then access the html of webview using

```
`NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];`
```